# Pair production intefering with gamma-ray laser black hole fabrication

Tags: black-holes, pair-production

A common "proposal" to make a micro black hole is to use on the order of 10^12 kg of gamma-ray lasing medium and focus all the light at a small point. However, intense light will interact with itself and produce particles such as electron and positrons, etc. Even visible light can do this, if it's strong enough (i.e. NIF pulsed laser intensity levels). Would this self-interaction create a cloud of hot plasma that "blurs" the focusing beams too much to make a black-hole?